# C# How do I compare two lists without sorting?

Tags: c#

I need to compare gammaFactorWeigths and gammaFactors and make sure they must have the same number of factors and must be in the same order in both inputs (guidance, planning, and goal).

I deserialized the input below. So I have a list of portfolios and a list of phases. I need to compare gammaFactor from portfolios and gammaFactorWeigths in phases which is a List of Lists. Can someone assist me how to do this? I would prefer a solution without lambdas.

```
public class AlphaCalcParam
    {
        public List<PortfolioInputModel> portfolios { get; set; }
        public List<PhaseInputModel> phases { get; set; }

        public bool Validation(ref string errString)
        {

            errString = "";
            return true;

            // check if gammaFactor and gammaFactorWeights match are in the same order
        }
    }
```

**Data Structure below:**

```
  {
    "portfolios":[
                {
                    "identifier": "id 1",
                    "gammaFactors":[
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Guidance",
                            "factorOffered":1
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Planning",
                            "factorOffered":0
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Goal",
                            "factorOffered":0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "identifier": "id 2",
                    "gammaFactors":[
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Guidance",
                            "factorOffered":1
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Planning",
                            "factorOffered":1
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Goal",
                            "factorOffered":1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "phases":[
                {

                    "identifier": "xyz",
                    "gammaFactorWeights":[
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Guidance",
                            "factorWeight":0.0075
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Planning",
                            "factorWeight":0.003
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Goal",
                            "factorWeight":0.0015
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "identifier": "xyz",
                    "gammaFactorWeights":[
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Guidance",
                            "factorWeight":0.005
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Planning",
                            "factorWeight":0.0025
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Goal",
                            "factorWeight":0.0015
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "identifier": "xyz",
                    "gammaFactorWeights":[
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Guidance",
                            "factorWeight":0.0025
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Planning",
                            "factorWeight":0.002
                        },
                        {
                            "factorIdentifier":"Goal",
                            "factorWeight":0.0015
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Do elements in gammaFactor list correspond 1 to 1 to elements in gammaFactorWeigths? Maybe I am trying to ask whether first element in portfolios have same identifier as first element in phases?

Comment: No, the identifiers are completely different in both the lists. I modified the data to keep things simple. I modified the data.

Comment: Please explain a bit more what do you want to compare. Or maybe describe the result you want to get.

Comment: Do elements in gammaFactor list correspond 1 to 1 to elements in gammaFactorWeigths?  - Yes. Need to compare factorIdentifier's for both gammaFactor and gammaFactorWeights. So Guidance, Planning, Goal should match the same both in portfolio and phase List.

Comment: Will for loop over portfolios and phases do the job? And for each index you can get gammaFactorWeights and gammaFactors and in nested loop compare what you need?

Comment: I originally tried this exact solution but I couldn't make it work. Yes this will do the job. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137847/discussion-between-mihir-patel-and-andrii-litvinov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach I am thinking of.

```
int length = Math.Min(portfolios.Count, phases.Count); // Only if collections can be of different length
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
     var portfolio = portfolios[i];
     var phase = phases[i];

     var factors = portfolio.gammaFactors;
     var weights = phase.gammaFactorWeights;

     var factorOffered = int.MaxValue;

     for (int j = 0; j < factors.Count; j++)
     {
          if (factors[j].factorOffered > factorOffered)
          {
              // Next factor is greater than current which fails validation.
              return false;
          }
          factorOffered = factors[j].factorOffered;
     }

     // Same can be done for weights.
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make this solution more dynamic? I don't want to assume what the string will be. So maybe wrap a loop around factors and weights? The data here is a mock data. In my actual data, I have 12 factorIdentifier which I think typing each one of them is perhaps not the best solution.

Comment: Good point you can remember previous factor weight and compare if it is greater than current. I will update my solution.